# Safari and Chromium on Mac get input language from other apps

Tags: macos, safari, google-chrome, input-source

In my system, two 'input sources' (languages) are enabled, and I use different languages in different 'documents' (apps).

I have Chromium or Safari open (a Webkit browser, that is to say) with English language selected for input. Then I switch to (for example) Skype where I use Russian. And when I switch back to the browser, it has Russian language selected as the current input language—the browser picks the language from another app.

This happens only when I switch to the web page itself. If I click in the address bar instead (from Skype or from the browser), the language will switch to English. And if I then put focus in the page again, it will still be English (i.e. the address bar acts as another 'document').

So, every time I switch to the browser to type something, I have to make sure I change the language to the proper one first. Languages seem to work fine in other respects across the system (though I recall having the same issue in the Terminal before but it disappeared, possibly with an update).

What could cause this behavior? Is there a solution? Is it a known issue?

Versions, for the record:

> OSX 10.8.5 (build 12F37)
>   Chromium 30.0.1599.101 (227552) from FreeSMUG
>   Safari 6.0.5 (8536.30.1)

All browser extensions are turned off, no Flash in the open pages (because this happens even on the 'new tab' page).
The issue is not new, I had it since 10.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp, since different input sources for different documents are no longer in OS X as of 10.9, I don't have the problem anymore.

Now I use Punto Switcher to switch the language for different applications, and it does that fine (although it seems to hang language switching altogether once in a while).